# Rails: quick way to set an attribute on all ActiveRecord Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Stupid question of the day...

```
fixup = Model.where(author_id: 5)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Model id: 243, author_id: 5, ...>, <#Model id: 573, author_id: 5, ...>]>

fixup.each do |f|
  f.author_id = 99
  f.save
end
```

What's the one-liner for a method like above that would change an attribute on each record in the ActiveRecord Relation? I'm drawing the stupid blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_all`. More info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)

```
fixup = Model.where(author_id: 5).update_all(author_id: 99)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work:

```
Model.where(author_id: 5).update_all(author_id: 99)
```

Take a look on [API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) for more details.